# can i publish outlook add-ins which target 2010, 2013 versions of outlook on the online office store

Tags: outlook-addin

I am planning to develop a outlook add-in which will work with the desktop version of outlook 2010 and 2013.

Can i publish it on the online office store (https://store.office.com/) or is it that the store only allows submission of office 365 apps???

I tried looking at the store's documentation but it does not mention anything on the topic.
I have tried contacting Microsoft support but they seem to have no clue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't publish COM add-ins to the Office store.

COM add-ins (like any other Windows desktop applications) can be published to the [Windows store](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/apps).

Answer (score 0):

Office Store only accepts JS based addins. COM addins for the desktop versions of Outlook cannot be distributed though the store.